# Does this multivariable non-negative function only have minima points?

Tags: maxima-minima

Consider multivariable functions of the form: $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i\right)^2$$ Can they only have minima points? If so, why?

I tried to plot some functions on Desmos and it looks like my hypothesis is correct, but maybe I'm missing something.

**Edit:** I removed the first question, as I realized it was too naïve.

Comment: Do you mean functions like $f(x) = e^x$? That's a non-negative function, but it doesn't have a smallest value.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? Are you looking to see whether other extrema than minima are possible with such functions, or do you want functions that only consist of minimal points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No.  One example is constant functions : every point is simultaneously a [global maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) and a [global minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima).  A less degenerate example is
   [image: Mathematica graphics]

   having a local maximum at $x = 0$.  Another is
   [image: Mathematica graphics]  
   In fact $\mathrm{e}^{P(x)}$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ having a global maximum (respectively, local maximum), is an everywhere positive function having a global maximum (resp., local maximum).
2. Yes or maybe, depending on your definitions.  Compute the various first partial derivatives to discover that the only possible [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) is at the origin, $x = (0,\dots, 0)$.  Here, the function is $0$, so there is both **a** local minimum and **a** global minimum at the origin.  However, note that if all the $a_i = 0$ then every point is simultaneously a global minimum and a global maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The function $x^2 e^{\left(-x^2\right)} + 1$ has global maxima at $x = \pm 1$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/llxnomd24q

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't answer my second question